# if situation when trying to read struct elements

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

I got this if problem. Whenever I run the program and I type the letter m when required,it is not reqognized by my if statement. Does someone know why ? I've been doing this for an hour, and no result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct firma{
    char nume[20];
    char prenume[20];
    char studii[5];
    int absolvire;
    char localitate[20];
    char facultate[20];

};

void citire(struct firma *angajati, int n){
     int i;

     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         printf("Angajatul nr.%d\n", i+1);
         printf("Nume: "); fflush(stdin); gets((angajati+i)->nume);
         printf("Prenume: "); fflush(stdin); gets((angajati+i)->prenume);
         printf("Studii: "); fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &(angajati+i)->studii);

         if(((angajati+i)->studii)=='m'){
             printf("Anul absolvirii liceului: "); 
             scanf("%d", &(angajati+i)->absolvire);
             printf("Localitatea: "); 
             fflush(stdin);      
             gets((angajati+i)->localitate);
         }
         if(((angajati+i)->studii)=='s'){
             printf("Anul absolvirii facultatii: "); 
             scanf("%d", &(angajati+i)->absolvire);
             printf("Localitatea: ");
             fflush(stdin); 
             gets((angajati+i)->localitate);
             printf("Facultatea absolvita: "); 
             fflush(stdin);
             gets((angajati+i)->facultate);
         }
     }
 }

int main()
{
    struct firma angajati[20];
    int n;

    printf("Introduceti numarul de angajati: "); 
    scanf("%d", &n);

    citire(angajati, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the value of `(angajati+i)->studii` to make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: It does not work wlike this scanf(" %c", &(angajati+i)->studii); 
And it's not printing the letter I want, just a weird up-arrow symbol, but i don;t know why.

Answer (score 4):

`firma->studii` is a char array, you are comparing a character 'm' with an address.

Please use `(angajati + i)->studii[0]` instead.